# Ember router: Asynchronous model (promises?)

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

[This is about the new 1.0.0-pre.4+ router.]

I want to return from an Ember Route's `model` method a record that needs asynchronous callbacks to load, for instance because it requires that we load multiple (nested) models. What's the best way to do this?

---

Here is sample code from a hypothetical blog app that illustrates the problem:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'filteredArticles', path: '/:filter'

App.FilteredArticlesRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    blog = App.Blog.find(1) # get the user's Blog singleton
    property = switch params.filter
      when 'published' then 'publishedArticles'
      when 'draft' then 'drafts'
      when 'all' then 'articles'
    # Return the list of articles from the `blog` record.
    # But `blog` hasn't necessarily finished loading :(
    blog.get(property)
```

Comment: As far as I know if you just return `blog.get(property)` it will return another promise, which will be fetched async.

Comment: I wish it did, but it just returns an empty array that never gets updated -- even when rerunning `App.Blog.find(1).get('articles')` yields a non-empty array.

Comment: That feels more of like a github issue to me :)

Comment: I've had similar issues (but when manipulating content in a controller), and resorted to `isLoaded` (https://gist.github.com/domchristie/4774472): a pattern inspired by the [Discourse source code](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/discourse/controllers/topic_controller.js.coffee#L65). Could you be experiencing [this issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1642)?

Comment: Thanks Dom - the code you linked doesn't solve the problem that the router expects you to return something immediately, but the issue discussion ([#1642](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1642)) looks very interesting.

Comment: Jo - yes: I realised it wasn't an ideal piece of code for this question, but thought it may add to the (perhaps more general) issue of how to deal with promises in ember?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm in the middle of rewriting [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org) to the newest ember version and I faced the same problem - we fetch repositories by slug (e.g. `emberjs/ember.js`), which is not the primary key. My solution involves using `Ember.ProxyObject`.

When someone enters the path like `/emberjs/ember.js`, the params will look like:

```
{ owner: 'emberjs', name: 'ember.js` }
```

and thus slug will equal `emberjs/ember.js`.

With such information, I create simple Ember object, which just keeps `slug` and `isLoaded` properties:

```
content = Ember.Object.create slug: slug, isLoaded: false
```

Then I create a proxy with this object as the content:

proxy = Ember.ObjectProxy.create(content: content)

Now I can load the record from the server using slug and return the proxy as the model. When I get the record from the server, I simply set proxies content to the actual record.

Full solution is here:

```
deserialize: (params) ->
  slug = "#{params.owner}/#{params.name}"
  content = Ember.Object.create slug: slug, isLoaded: false
  proxy = Ember.ObjectProxy.create(content: content)

  repos = Travis.Repo.bySlug(slug)

  observer = ->
    if repos.get 'isLoaded'
      repos.removeObserver 'isLoaded', observer
      proxy.set 'content', repos.objectAt(0)

  if repos.length
    proxy.set('content', repos[0])
  else
    repos.addObserver 'isLoaded', observer

  proxy
```

You can also take a look at the rest of the code [on github](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-web/blob/5245b7f/assets/scripts/app/routes.coffee#L472-L489)

Answer (score 0):

How about you add an observer in the model itself, on the isLoaded status of the model and then call `blog.get(property)`

```
blogReady: function() {
  if(this.get('isLoaded') {
     // switch logic
  }
}.observes('isLoaded')
```